# How to convert function into widget for html embedding in Jupyter notebook

Tags: user-interface, jupyter-notebook, widget

I have the following code which plots the price of the stock price of a company. Entering for example AAPL into the box provides the stock price of apple.

```
    import ipywidgets as ipw
    import pandas_datareader as pdr
    import datetime
    from datetime import datetime
    import numpy as np
    import scipy as sp
    import pandas as pd
    from __future__ import print_function
    from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
    from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html
    from ipywidgets.embed import embed_data

    nbox=ipw.Text(
        value='Stock handle',
        placeholder='Type something',
        description='String:',
        disabled=False        
            )


    def company(ticker):
        strt=datetime(2020,1,1)
        end=datetime.now()
        dat=pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, strt, end)
        return dat['Close'].plot(grid=True)

    w=interact_manual(company,ticker=nbox)
```

when i check type(w) it tell me w is a function not a widget. My question is how do i make w into a widget. I want to then embed the widget.

Please do not provide any print_me or such examples. Instead any example using the company function would be nice. Thanks for any help.